# Prove that the closed unit ball is closed directly.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following theorem, and I'm not sure my proof holds.

> **Theorem.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $p\in X$, and $r >0$. Then $$E = \left\{x\in X\ |\ d(x,p)\leq r\right\}$$ is a closed subset of
>   $X$.
>
> *Proof.* $E$ is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points. Let $\{x_n\} \subset E$ such that $x_n \to x$. We claim that
>   $x \in E$. Since $x_n$ converges, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists
>   an $N$, such that for all $n \geq N$, $d(x,x_n) < \epsilon.$
>
> By the triangle inequality $d(p,x) \leq d(p, x_n) + d(x_n, x)$ and so
>   $d(p,x) < r + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. **So, at the least
>   $d(p,x) \leq r$**, and $x$ is contained in E. The proof is complete.

Is my bolded step  logically wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The proof is correct (and neat).

Comment: Yes.And for future reference, $ E$ is not necessarily the closure of $ F=\{y \in X : d(y,p)<r\}$. For example if  $ X=\{p,q\}$ with $ p \ne q$,  and $d(p,q)=1 = r.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Disclaimer:** This might be a little bit too nitpicky on my part.]

First $E$ is not a unit closed ball, it's an $r$-closed-ball if you like.

More important than that, your bolded step does not really add anything to the previous sentence, viz., we have $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$a\leq b \iff \forall \varepsilon>0: a<b+\varepsilon.$$

Comment: So you can delete the words "at the least".

Comment: @user254665 I'd say.