# Prove that $G = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2<|x|+|y|<3\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to solve for the first quadrant of the graph first. There, we can simplify the expression for the subset $G$ as:
$$
2<x+y<3
$$

Taking $(x_0, y_0) \in G_I$ (pairs of $(x,y)$ that belongs to $G$ in first quadrant of the graph) and
$$
r = \min\biggl( 
\frac{|x_0+y_0-2|}{\sqrt{2}},\, 
\frac{|x_0+y_0-3|}{\sqrt{2}}
\biggr), 
$$
we can construct an open ball so that for any $(x', y') \in B\bigl((x_0, y_0), r\bigr)$, we'd like show that $(x', y') \in G_I$.

How can I show that $(x', y') \in G_I$? I imagine the solution is analogous for remaining quadrants.

Comment: I don't know what you can assume about open sets but splitting into quadrants seems like a needless complication to me.

Comment: Inverse image of $(2,3)$ under a continuous function is open.

Comment: Also, for your chosen value of $r$, you cannot prove that $(x',y')\in G_I$. If you take $x_0 = 2.5$ and $y_0 = \frac1{10000000}$. Then your ball intersects the quadrant below. Don't forget to treat points on the axes as well

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for the observation. So $r$ could be taken as $Min(\frac{|x_0+y_0-2|}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{|x_0+y_0-3|}{\sqrt{2}}, x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: Since  $G=B(O,3)\setminus\overline{B(O,2)}$ for the $1$-norm $\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|,$ the following answers your question: [Closed balls are closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400239/closed-balls-are-closed).

Comment: Since $f(x,y)= |x|+|y|$ is continuous, if $f(x,y) \in (2,3)$ then there is some small ball around $(x,y)$ for which this is true too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on geetha290krm's comment:

The functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto \vert t \vert$ are continuous. Thus the composite
$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
g:\mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow& \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow& \mathbb{R}\\
(x,y) &\mapsto& (\vert x\vert,\vert y \vert) &\mapsto& \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert
\end{array}$$
is continuous as composition of continuous functions. The subset $(2,3) \subseteq \mathbb R$ is an open interval, hence open. Thus the preimage $G = g^{-1}((2,3)) \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is open.